# Locate all indices of a number in a list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of matrices (2 rows and different number of columns in each matrix). The first row in each matrix is of interest here. I want an efficient way of finding the column in each element of the list which takes a certain value. The first row of each element of the list has all unique values. Consider the example list below.

```
> example <- list(matrix(1:6, nrow = 2), matrix(c(1,5,6,4,3,6,4,6,7,9), nrow = 2), matrix(c(1,7,5,9), nrow = 2))
> example
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6    3    4    7
[2,]    5    4    6    6    9

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    5
[2,]    7    9
```

If I want to find the occurrences of the number "3", in the first row of each element of the list, the returned object will look like,

```
> index <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0), ncol = 2)
> index
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    3
[3,]    3    0
```

where the output matrix says that "3" occurs in the 1st element at column 2, in the 2nd element at column 3, and does not occur in the 3rd element.

I can use a double for loop, I was hoping there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just applies `which()` over the list, on the first row of each element, and gives a zero if the result has no length (is `integer(0)`).  Then we bind that to a sequence the length of `s` (or the length of `example`, same thing).

```
s <- lapply(example, function(x) {
    if(!length(w <- which(x[1,] == 3))) 0 else w
})

cbind(seq_along(s), unlist(s))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    2    3
# [3,]    3    0
```